# From cross correlation to column format in R

Tags: r, cross-correlation

I have the following cross-correlation matrix:

df =

```
   A B C
A  1 7 1
B  7 1 9
C  1 9 1
```

and I would like to make it into the following format:

```
A B 7
A C 1
B C 9
```

any straightforward R code that can do such thing?

Comment: Get the ["SOfun" package](http://mrdwab.github.io/SOfun/index.html) and do `library(SOfun); dist2df(as.dist(mat))`. Or perhaps do `as.data.frame(as.table(mat))[lower.tri(mat), ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a straightforward way but an option in base R :

```
mat[upper.tri(mat, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
tmp <- which(!is.na(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(col = colnames(mat)[tmp[, 2]], row = rownames(tmp), val = mat[tmp])

#  col row val
#1   A   B   7
#2   A   C   1
#3   B   C   9
```

**data**

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 1L), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "C")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option

```
inds <- which(col(mat) < row(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)
data.frame(
  col = colnames(mat)[inds[, "col"]],
  row = rownames(mat)[inds[, "row"]],
  val = mat[inds]
)
```

gives

```
  col row val
1   A   B   7
2   A   C   1
3   B   C   9
```